# Find (num * (pow(b, p) - 1) / den) % mod where p is very large(10 ^ 18)

Tags: binary, exponentiation

I want to find (num * (pow(b, p) - 1) / den) % mod. I know about binary exponentiation. But we can't do it straightforward. It is guaranteed that the numerator is divisible by the denominator. That means

[num * (pow(b, p) - 1)] % den == 0

constraints on mod: are 1 <= mod <= 10 ^ 9 and mod might be prime or composite

constraints on b: 1 <= b <= 10

constraints on p: 1 <= p <= (10^18)

constraints on num: 1 <= num <= (10^9)

constraints on den: 1 <= den <= (10^9)

Here pow(b, p) means b raised to power p(b ^ p). It is guaranteed that the numerator is divisible by the denominator. How can I do it with binary exponentiation

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to give precisions? Are b and p integers? The title states modulo (remainder), while in the  text it is division (quotient). The denominator is always 2? Finding either modulo or quotient is not a real problem in that case. And "It is guaranteed that the numerator is divisible by the denominator" means that p is even, right? Last, you say "p is very large". Does it means the result may not fit in a standard integer. Can you give order of magnitude of b and p?

Comment: @AlainMerigot Sorry, the question was not properly framed. I have edited the question. Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression should rewritten to simplIfy it. First let k=num/den, with k integer according to your question.

So you have to compute
(k×(b^p-1))mod m=( (k mod m) × ((b^p -1) mod m) ) mod m
                           = ( (k mod m) × ( (b^p mod m) -1 mod m ) mod m ) mod m
                           = ((k mod m) × ((b^p mod m) + m-1) mod m) mod m             (1)

So the real problem is to compute b^p mod m

Many languages (python, java, etc) already have a modular exponentiation in their standard libraries. Consult the documentation and use it. Otherwise, here is a C implementation.

```
unsigned long long modexp(unsigned long long b, unsigned long long e, unsigned long long m) {
  if (m==1) return 0;
  unsigned long long res=1;
  unsigned long long bb = b % m;
  while (e) {
    if (e & 1) 
      res = (res*b) % m;
    e >>= 1;
    bb = (bb*bb) % m;
  }
  return res;
}
```

The implementation uses `long long` to fit your constraints. It relies on the classical trick of binary exponentiation. All values of b^l, where l is a power of two (l=2^t) are computed and stored in var bb and if the corresponding t<sup>th</sup> bit of e is set, this value of b^l is integrated in the result. Bit testing is done by checking the successive parities of e, while shifting e rightward at each step.

Last, the fact that (a×b)mod m=((a mod m)×(b mod m))mod m is used to avoid computation on very large numbers. We always have res<m and bb<m and hence res and bb are codable on standard integers.

Then you just have to apply (1) to get the final result.

EDIT according to the precisions given in the comments
To compute n=(3^p-1)/2 mod m, one can remark that
(3^p-1)/2 = x*m + n    (as 3^p-1 is even, x is an integer, 0≤n<m)
3^p-1=x*2*m+2n         (0≤2n<2m)
so 2n=(3^p-1) mod 2m

We can just apply the previous method with a modulo of 2*m, and divide the result (that will be even) by 2.

Comment: well, num/den is not necessarily an integer. The product of num and that power term is divisible by den. We can easily calculate the entire numerator term mod m. But then we can't divide this term with denominator term directly. We could have used modular inverse if mod were prime. But here it is not the case. How to do this

Comment: How can guaranty that num*(b^p-1)=k*den with k integer?

Comment: If num = 5,  b = 3, p = 4, den = 10 and k = 40. the equation is satisfied.

Comment: Of course, it is possible. But how is it guaranteed?

Comment: Forget that. I want to calculate (((3 ^ n) - 1) / 2)  % mod for a really large n(10 ^ 18) and p not necessarily prime. Of course (3 ^ n) - 1 will be even. How to do this

Comment: With simple mathematical transforms, this problem can be turned to the previous one. See edits in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195519/discussion-between-nikhil-rathore-and-alain-merigot).

Comment: Can I replace 2 with any other number. In particular can I replace it with 8

Comment: The only assumption is that (3^p-1)/d must be an integer for the equality and the rewriting are correct. If it is true, then you can do the replacement. But insuring that a number is a multiple a 8 is not as easy as for 2 but is true for some values.  3^2=8+1 and every 3^p with p even will be of the form 8k+1. But it is not true for p odd.

Comment: Okay but I also want to find 18 * (9^n - 1) / 8. If the numerator term is divisible by denominator then can we write it as [(18 * (9^n - 1)) % (8 * m)] / 8

Comment: Yes. And  9^n is always of the form 8n+1, so it will work. And you also have to recompute the modulo after multiplying by 18.